# ¿Add [""] to ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I convert this:

```
https://myimage.com
```

to this in ruby?

```
["https://myimage.com"]
```

I've tried with join with no luck...

Thanks

Comment: `s = "https://myimage.com"; s2 = "[\"#{s}\"]"` or `s2 = '["' + s + '"]'` or (many other options)? It's not clear what specific issue you're having since we can't see your code, or in what context you're trying to do this.

Comment: Are both 'before' and 'after' Ruby strings? What's your goal with the second string that requires that format?

Comment: Presumably, `https://myimage.com` should be `"https://myimage.com"` and `["https://myimage.com"]` is an array containing one string, as shown, in which case just write that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what you're looking to accomplish. You can't really turn `https://myimage.com` into anything, since it is not valid Ruby syntax.

However, if you first have it as a string, then you can easily put it inside of an array like this:

```
url    = 'https://myimage.com'
result = [url]
puts result.inspect
#=> ["https://myimage.com"]
```

Or if instead you want a string as your result, then here yah go:

```
url    = 'https://myimage.com'
result = '["' + url + '"]'
puts result
#=> ["https://myimage.com"]
```